# Get mean and interval from simulated var

Tags: r, data.table, simulation

I have a dataset like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(EnvStats)
library(bayestestR)

DT <- data.table(MEAN = c(0.5,0.7,0.9),MIN = c(0.4,0.6,0.8),MAX = c(0.6,0.8,1),REF = rnorm(3,1000,200))
```

I compute a var with simulated values from vars `MEAN`, `MIN` and `MAX`.

```
DT[,Sim_rtri := list(REF*(1+rtri(n = 1000,min = MIN,max = MAX,mode = MEAN)))]
```

But I get the same values ​​for each row even though I need the simulation to take the values ​​for each row. How can I do this?

And, I want to get the two vars using, one with the mean of var `Sim_rtri` and other with an interval of that var, I tried this:

```
DT[,Mean_Sim_rtri := mean(Sim_rtri)]
DT[,Int_Sim_rtri := ci(Sim_rtri, method = "ETI",ci = .95)]
```

But I get errors from that. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes clearer when you do not assign your first line of code:

```
set.seed(42)
DT <- data.table(MEAN = c(0.5,0.7,0.9),MIN = c(0.4,0.6,0.8),MAX = c(0.6,0.8,1),REF = rnorm(3,1000,200))
DT[,list(REF*(1+rtri(n = 1000,min = MIN,max = MAX,mode = MEAN)))]
            V1
   1: 1946.223
   2: 1465.333
   3: 2056.410
   4: 1940.845
   5: 1504.171
  ---         
 996: 1968.724
 997: 1962.222
 998: 1511.566
 999: 2037.884
1000: 1810.734
Warning message:
In REF * (1 + rtri(n = 1000, min = MIN, max = MAX, mode = MEAN)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

It is creating one list of length 1000 rather than 3 list-columns (each 1000) because it is recycling the values from the `data.table` (notice how the *general* pattern of `V1` is ~`1900...1500...2000`. Anyway, there may be a more idiomatic/`data.table` way to solve the issue but does using `Map()` line up more with the results you would expect?

```
set.seed(42)
DT <- data.table(MEAN = c(0.5,0.7,0.9),MIN = c(0.4,0.6,0.8),MAX = c(0.6,0.8,1),REF = rnorm(3,1000,200))
DT[, Sim_rtri := Map(function(w, x, y, z) w*(1+rtri(n = 1000,min = x,max = y,mode = z)), REF, MIN, MAX, MEAN)]
DT[, Mean_Sim_rtri := sapply(Sim_rtri, mean)]
DT[, Int_Sim_rtri := lapply(Sim_rtri, ci, method = "ETI",ci = .95)]

DT
   MEAN MIN MAX       REF                                                  Sim_rtri Mean_Sim_rtri     Int_Sim_rtri
1:  0.5 0.4 0.6 1274.1917 1946.223,1849.996,1933.170,1940.845,1905.784,1943.204,...      1908.901 <bayestestR_eti>
2:  0.7 0.6 0.8  887.0604 1512.938,1530.315,1480.203,1542.298,1500.740,1513.961,...      1507.717 <bayestestR_eti>
3:  0.9 0.8 1.0 1072.6257 2055.113,2085.123,1991.335,2022.209,2010.288,1984.313,...      2038.466 <bayestestR_eti>
```